# serialVersionUID from old class is too big

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm getting this error when trying to deserialize an old class:
`Failed to load game save: com.cpjd.thinkinsidethebox.b.a; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8253205603766639690, local class serialVersionUID = -4763228482499590571`

So of course, I just replaced `-4763228482499590571` with `8253205603766639690` in Android Studio. However, the latter is too big
to store in a long. How did Android manage to serialize something with a over 64-bit number and how do I fix it to maintain compatibility?

Comment: Do not deserialize old classes! Serialization is meant for short time storage, EG a server writes temporal data to disk before a restart. Your message suggest that the class changed since being serialized....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was just to use `8253205603766639690L`.